# Pending Transaction doesn't disappear out of Apple Wallet

Tags: apple-pay, wallet, apple-card

I made a purchase through the Apple Store app using Apple Pay and my Apple Card. After 45 days the pending transaction still appears along with the final charge. All of my reports in Apple Wallet show the total of both charges even though I only made one purchase.

How do I remove this duplicate pending transaction?

Answer (score 3):

To remove the duplicate transaction you need to refresh your Apple Wallet transactions by removing your Apple Card and re-adding it.

Go to Apple Wallet, select your Apple Card, click the 3 dots on the top right, scroll to the bottom, and click on Remove This Card.

You can then add your card back by clicking the + on the top right of the main Apple Wallet screen. Once it's added back, your transactions should be refreshed and the pending transaction should be gone.

Comment: Thanks  ALOT I wasted significant time with Apple text Support and got nowhere. This worked beautifully.